# Atomikos + Jetty in a Maven build environment - Classloader issue?

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, jta, atomikos

I am working on a project with multiple JDBC data sources and JTA. I use Maven as a build tool, and I'd like to use the Jetty plugin (6.1.20) to run the application during development.

I am trying to configure Jetty to use [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/) as the transaction manager. I'm following the [Atomikos documentation from Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Atomikos), but the Jetty startup fails with what looks like a class loader issue.

Here are the relevant bits of my configuration.

`runtime` scope dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
    <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.7</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
    <artifactId>transactions-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.7</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

My `jetty-env.xml` located in `/WEB-INF` (autodiscovered by Jetty):

```
<New id="userTxImpl" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" />

<New id="tx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction">
    <Arg>
        <Ref id="userTxImpl" />
    </Arg>
</New>
```

The instantiation of `tx` at the end is the bit that fails, if I leave it out, Jetty starts up fine (but does not expose `UserTransaction` via JNDI, of course).

The Stacktrace:

```
    2009-09-02 18:42:18.910::WARN:  Config error at <New id="tx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction"><Arg>
            <Ref id="userTxImpl"/>
        </Arg></New>
2009-09-02 18:42:18.910::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@12515db{/administrator,C:\workspace\administrator\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Constructor: <New id="tx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction"><Arg>
            <Ref id="userTxImpl"/>
        </Arg></New> on org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@12515db{/administrator,C:\workspace\administrator\src\main\webapp}
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:631)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:190)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configureWebApp(EnvConfiguration.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:124)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:579)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmentForProject(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute_aroundBody0(DefaultMaven.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute_aroundBody1$advice(DefaultMaven.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:1)
    at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute_aroundBody2(MavenEmbedder.java:904)
    at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute_aroundBody3$advice(MavenEmbedder.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.embedder.MavenEmbedder.execute(MavenEmbedder.java:1)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
```

This looks like a classloader issue, as `org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction` has got a Constructor taking a `javax.transaction.UserTransaction`, and `com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp` implements `javax.transaction.UserTransaction`, yet Jetty complains it does not have a proper constructor to use.

I'm obviously missing something here, but what is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have multiple copies of the `UserTransaction` class kicking around in your deployment. If these are loaded from different classloaders, then you can end up with this sort of error.

Check Jetty's libraries for `UserTransaction`, and then check your application's libraries. You should only have one copy.

Comment: An indirect dependency on jboss-j2ee, which comes with its own UserTransaction, was the problem. Thanks so much! I thought I was going mad.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you should not be specifying the JTA jar as a 'runtime' requirement, but rather as a 'provided' requirement.  Similar to servlet-api and JMS, the individual implementers provide their own copies of the API and providing the Sun jar can muck them up.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is already answered, but I wanna put up my experience to save others the grief I just went through.

I had a similar problem, but it was caused by a conflict in versions of geronimo-jta spec.  Specifically the one depended on by atomikos wasn't getting along with the one used by jetty.  I had to exclude the one from atomikos, e.g.:

com.atomikos
   transactions-essentials-all
   3.5.9
   
    
     org.apache.geronimo.specs
     geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec

Answer (score 0):

Like Taylor, I just blew a couple hours on this exact same issue.  I use Hibernate as a JPA provider and it had a Maven depdency on its own JTA User Tranaction.  Once I excluded this dependency I got past the issue.